# How to generate JMeter Composite Graph using CLI?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a test plan with Composite Graph inside it. Everything is working fine when using GUI. Unfortunately, I got this error when trying to generate that graph using [CLI](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/):

```
$ ~/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --generate-png test.png --input-jtl hg-cws-test-plan-v3.jtl --plugin-type CompositeGraph
2020-03-25 01:42:39,154 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Exception 'null' occurred when fetching String property:'sampleresult.default.encoding', defaulting to: ISO-8859-1
2020-03-25 01:42:39,178 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Exception 'null' occurred when fetching String property:'jmeterPlugin.prefixPlugins'
2020-03-25 01:42:39,181 INFO k.a.j.PluginsCMDWorker: Using JMeterPluginsCMD v. N/A
2020-03-25 01:42:39,191 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_MY
2020-03-25 01:42:39,205 INFO k.a.j.JMeterPluginsUtils: Loading user properties from: /Users/zulhilmi/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/user.properties
2020-03-25 01:42:39,206 INFO k.a.j.JMeterPluginsUtils: Loading system properties from: /Users/zulhilmi/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/system.properties
ERROR: java.lang.ClassCastException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CompositeResultCollector cannot be cast to kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
*** Problem's technical details go below ***
Home directory was detected as: /Users/zulhilmi/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/lib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CompositeResultCollector cannot be cast to kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.doJob(PluginsCMDWorker.java:111)
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.ReporterTool.processParams(ReporterTool.java:255)
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:62)
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:115)
```

What did I missed here? What does that `kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CompositeResultCollector cannot be cast to kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector` actually means here?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [Plugin Type Cases](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/#Plugin-Type-Classes) I fail to see `CompositeGraph` there:

> - AggregateReport = JMeter's native Aggregate Report, can be saved only as CSV
> - SynthesisReport = mix between JMeter's native Summary Report and Aggregate Report, can be saved only as CSV
> - ThreadsStateOverTime = Active Threads Over Time
> - BytesThroughputOverTime
> - HitsPerSecond
> - LatenciesOverTime
> - PerfMon = PerfMon Metrics Collector
> - DbMon = DbMon Metrics Collector, DataBase, get performance counters via sql
> - JMXMon = JMXMon Metrics Collector, Java Management Extensions counters
> - ResponseCodesPerSecond
> - ResponseTimesDistribution
> - ResponseTimesOverTime
> - ResponseTimesPercentiles
> - ThroughputVsThreads
> - TimesVsThreads = Response Times VS Threads
> - TransactionsPerSecond
> - PageDataExtractorOverTime
> - MergeResults = MergeResults Command Line Merge Tool to simplify the comparison of two or more load tests, need properties file (like merge-results.properties)

So most probably you're trying to call the functionality which hasn't been implemented yet.

You can reach out to the plugins developers/maintainers at [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins), they better know the product than anyone here.

In the meantime you can consider alternative solution like [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) where you can create whatever composite charts you want using a fancy web interface. The [BM.Sense Uploader](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/sense-uploader/LoadosophiaUploader.md) plugin can be used for automatically uploading the results during the test execution.